# Disproving a linear transformation from $ \mathbb{C} $ to $ M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C}) $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a linear transformation $ T : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow  M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C}), T(z) =  \begin{bmatrix}x&y\\-y&x\end{bmatrix} $ where $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$ and $x,y \in \mathbb{R} $.

I'm fairly certain that closure under addition is satisfied, but not scalar multiplication by the scalar $ i $.

So let $u = u_1+u_2i$, then $T(u) = \begin{bmatrix}u_1&u_2\\-u_2&u_1\end{bmatrix} $.

Multiplying by $i$, $T(i u) = T(u_1 i - u_2)$.
I'm kind of confused at this step. What would the output look like? Does $x$ and $y$ in the definition of $T$ correspond to the $x$ and $y$, or does it correspond to the real and imaginary parts, respectively?

In the former scenario then we have
$T(i u) = T(u_1 i - u_2) = \begin{bmatrix}u_1&-u_2\\-u_2&u_1\end{bmatrix}$
and in the latter, we have
$$T(i u) = T(u_1 i - u_2) = T(-u_2 + u_1 i) = \begin{bmatrix}-u_2&u_1\\-u_1&-u_2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Which is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: $T(1)=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, $T(1)=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}\ne iT(1)$.

Comment: maybe Angina Seng wanted to say that $T(i)\neq iT(1)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map is linear if we consider $\mathbb{C}$ and $M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C})$ as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.

It is not $\mathbb{C}$-linear and a simple example is
$$
T(i)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\ne
iT(1)=i\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
This suffices to disprove $\mathbb{C}$-linearity.

What's the image of $T(iz)$ according to the definition? If $z=x+yi$, with $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, you have $iz=-y+xi$ and therefore, according to the definition,
$$
T(iz)=\begin{bmatrix} -y & x \\ -x & -y \end{bmatrix}
$$
which cannot generally equal $iT(z)$, because $T(z)$ has real entries (the only case in which $T(iz)=iT(z)$ is when $z=0$).